# Submitted wrong file while submitting the revision

Tags: publications, peer-review, journals, paper-submission, editors

My paper has been accepted in a journal with minor revision. However, while submitting the revision I mistakenly submitted a wrong file. What to do in this case ? Should I inform the editor ? Thanks

Comment: Yes.  Inform the editor.  Now!

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you need to contact the editor immediately. You don't want them to waste time putting the wrong version into the production system. If the submission was online, they may have to reset the system to permit the update (or not). You can offer to send the paper directly.

If an online system permits an update, then do that, but also inform the editor so that there is some assurance that things are put right.